# Arabic characters are not recognized

Tags: sql, loader, multilingual

I am trying to load Arabic characters into a table using SQL loader. What are  the prerequisites and what all parameters need to be set? I am getting "?" in the CSV file.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic first

Answer (score 0):

you need a character set that can represent Arabic characters and you need to make sure all the software involved agrees on your choice.

I'd try utf-8 first